# Javascript - How to push an array to a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I trying to push an array I've generated to a multidimensional array, and for some reason the value of all the other positions in the array's values, are the same as the value I just pushed.

For example: I do

```
var grades = [];

for(var i = 0; i < num_qes + 1; i++){
        var grade = [0, 0, 0, 0];

        grade[0] = i;
        for(var n = 0; n < num_qes+ 1; n++){
            grade[1] = n;
            for(var f = 0; f < num_qes+ 1; f++){
                grade[2] = f;
                for(var t = 0; t < num_qes+ 1; t++){
                    grade[3] = t;

                    allGrad = grade[0] + grade[1] +  grade[2] + grade[3];

                    //println(allGrad);

                    if(allGrad === num_qes){
                        grades.push(grade);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Here at the end I check to see if all of the values in my generated array are exactly equal to the number of questions.

```
  if(allGrad === num_qes){
     grades.push(grade);
  }
```

Let's say that `grade = [9, 1, 0, 0]`, when I push this value to the multidimensional array, grades, all the values change to `[9, 1, 0, 0]`. So the multidimensional array looks like this: `[[9, 1, 0, 0], [9, 1, 0, 0], [9, 1, 0, 0]]`, when it SHOULD look like this: `[[9, 0, 0, 1], [9, 0, 1, 0], [9, 1, 0, 0]]`.

I hope what I said make senses, and thanks in advance for ansnewing.

The jsfiddle is right [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o1awtzpc/)

Comment: Could you add a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with a not-working example for better understanding please.

Comment: Are you trying to get all combinations where the sum of the 4 values equals num_qes?

Comment: Yes, I only need all the combinations where the sum is 4.

Comment: The jsfiddle is right [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o1awtzpc/), I'm trying to get the page to display the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
var grades = [];
var num_qes = 4;

for(var i = 0; i <= num_qes; i++){
  for(var n = 0; n <= num_qes; n++){
    for(var f = 0; f <= num_qes; f++){
      for(var t = 0; t <= num_qes; t++){
        var sum = i + n + f + t;

        if(sum === num_qes){
          console.log(i + ',' + n + ',' + f + ',' + t);

          var grade = [i, n, f, t];
          grades.push(grade);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notes:

- I've replaced `i < num_qes + 1` with `i <= num_ques` for simplicity
- Only creating the grade array in the inner loop when your condition is met (makes it much more readable)
- Summing the numbers directly rather than reading from the grade array you've just populated (again more readable)
- Using console.log() to output results that match criteria

Results in console look like this...

```
0,0,0,4
0,0,1,3
0,0,2,2
0,0,3,1
0,0,4,0
0,1,0,3
0,1,1,2
0,1,2,1
0,1,3,0
etc
```

Comment: I'll try this out, Thank!

Comment: I still have other problems, but I'll figure those out on my own

Comment: What are your other problems? Writing results to the html page?

Comment: I figured out the problem.